# GoogleMap: Multiple Markers showing same InfoWindow and not clickable on Mobile Devices

Tags: google-maps, mobile, geolocation, google-maps-markers, infowindow

Problem with "Multiple Markers InfoWindows" on Google Map API.
There are 2 problems:

- Markers are showing **SAME InfoWindow**
- Again, Markers are **NOT CLICKABLE on mobile devices**.

Here is my code:

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(60.037760, -44.100494),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var locations = [
                    ['Alvin', 60.074433, -44.011917],
                    ['Sirius', 60.037760, -44.100494]
                ];

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: locations[i][0]});

    new google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create global reference to infowindow.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    new google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
         infowindow.open(map,this);
    });
}
```

Comment: Not working :( Worse result is that: Markers can't be clickable even on PC. Same on Mobile devices.